# check if my ethernet controller supports gigabit Ethernet

Tags: ubuntu, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

Is there a *command* that i can issue in Ubuntu to see explicitly if my ethernet controller supports *gigabit ethernet*?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As root, run `ethtool eth0` if eth0 is the NIC in question.  You'll get an output like:

```
Settings for eth0:
Supported ports: [ TP ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 1000Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: Twisted Pair
PHYAD: 1
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
Supports Wake-on: g
Wake-on: g
Current message level: 0x000000ff (255)
Link detected: yes
```

Should be all the info you need.

Comment: Cool, didn't knew about that.

Answer (score 9):

`lspci` should show it like "blah blah Gigabit 10/100/1000 blah blah controller". Like that. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
lspci | grep Ethernet
```

This should show information about your Ethernet controller and it should tell you your connection is 10G, 1G or other. You can also google the name of the ethernet controller for more information.